# Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@2f410acf

Tags: java, maven, testng

Please provide steps to how to install surefire plugin in Maven. I have googled and found no specific answer. There were lots of answer about the solution but no specific answer on how to install the plugin with steps.

Excpetion I am getting:

Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@2f410acf

pom.xml i use :

```
 <!-- language: xml --><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>au.com.simcentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>Example20</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jvnet.hudson.dom4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1-hudson-3</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hellojavaer/poi-excel-utils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hellojavaer</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-excel-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-BETA19</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <vertx.version>3.0.0-milestone5</vertx.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    </project>
```

Comment: can you share the pom.xml file?

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat . i have updated my question with the pom.xml file i use. please refer question body for the pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the attached pom.xml file, it is evident that inclusion of the surefire plugin is missing. Maven needs to know what plugin to include and which version. The following is suggested:

**Add the Maven Surefire plugin entry in the pom.xml file**

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>for example: 2.22.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Then run **mvn test**

The usage example above has been extracted from [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html)

Going a bit further, you can also include/exclude tests using the **configuration** schema

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>for example: 2.22.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>IncludeTest.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
         <exclude>ExcludeTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement></build>
```

A detailed instruction with examples is shown [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

**Incase you would like surefire to hook to your testng.xml**

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Upon success, the surefire plugin will generate a XML report at **target/reports** inside your project folder.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time . i have tried different solutions including the methods you have mentioned above and  it didn't solve my problem. so after many hours i have found a reason caused for my problem and the solution for it (like something we rarely figure out). i will update the answer below.  Thank you once again !

Answer (score 0):

After so many researchers i have found the solution for my problem. in first place i thought there is a problem in my pom.xml file. but after make sure my pom.xml is correct i figure out system does not displays/recognized the maven in my machine. (**mvn test**) .
As the solution i followed below steps and now the system doesn't give me the exception i mentioned above in my question .

1. open cmd and type mvn test (in my case system didnt recognized the mvn)
2. Navigate to path > edit the system variables> Environment variables >select system variable- path
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWs0n.png)

3.click on edit button and add the machine path which maven is available in to the end of the available path .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYDLS.png)

4.click ok

5.open cmd

6.type cmd test <>

7.now you can run your Maven project without the exception i have mentioned in my question :)

Comment: good to know that the error could be solved. However it is quite intriguing that the actual cause for the problem was the setup of maven in the environment! In my opinion, in future you could achieve fast and quick solution to the problem/s with the actual problem mentioned in the title or in the description. Based on the details provided, I had the impression that you were having problems with configuring testng with maven. Happy Testing, happy coding :)